# C: Taking int array as input without loop?

Tags: c, arrays

So I have this code:

```
int main(){
 printf("How many members are they?");
 int howManyMember;
 scanf("%d",&howManyMember);
 int theListOfNumber[howManyMember];
 /* Asks for some user entered numbers */
 /* Then prints the array */
 return 0;
}
```

I'd like to ask for the "previously user entered" amount of number from the user, but I'm told not to ask in loop so something like this is not expected.

```
int x;
for (x=0;x<howManyMember; x++){
 scanf("%d",&theListOfNumber[x])
}
```

So when I get the input, I will get the input as

```
arrayMember0 arrayMember1 ... arrayMemberN
```

not

```
arrayMember0
arrayMember1
arrayMember...
arrayMemberN
```

I tried `fgets()`but it turns out only for string. Any help will be appreciated =)

Note: Please do note, that how many number is asked is not fixed. It is based on user input.
Thanks!

Comment: Any chance that you could `fgets()` the whole input then split the string on the number separator character (looks like it is SPACE)?

Comment: `goto`? It's not technically a loop......

Comment: also, the code won't compile - as you should dynamically allocate memory for `theListOfNumber` and the user input value

Comment: @NirMH: C99 supports VLAs (which is what `int theListOfNumber[howManyMember]` is).

Comment: Please don't be a code nazis ! I just write this on the fly! I beg your mercy! =p

Comment: Realdo - we just try to help you ask a question that in few years will still be correct - please fix the code to make it work... or flag it as pseudo-code so people reading this will not get wrong ideas... and also - are you using C99 for the language?

Comment: OK, but only if you promise not to be a code profaner (he who disgraces the holiness of decent coding principles).

Comment: Is there any more input after this list of numbers?  If not, you simply need to read until you reach EOF or end of array (you won't access members out of bounds, will you?).  You can use a fixed allocation and stop when the array is full, or you can use dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()` et al) to give you complete flexibility on how much space is allocated for the array.  You should always check the return value from `scanf()` to ensure you got the input you were expecting.

Comment: If I'm getting this correct, you actually are all fine with it being achieved with or without a loop. You only want it to be able to receive the input with a space-delimited single-line of numbers. Your title therefore is a little deceiving, and your code is all fine on doing what you want.

Comment: Title has "without loop", and question body has "told not to ask in loop", so I think the intention is clear.

Comment: @jxh There is not a single sane solution to this problem that does not involve loops. From the way I get it, the only thing he needs is to be able to get numbers side by side, separated with spaces.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: Puzzles are not always sane.

Comment: `arrayMemberN` --> `arrayMember(N-1)`

Answer (score 2):

The code you have,

```
for (int x=0;x<howManyMember; x++){
 scanf("%d", &theListOfNumber[x])
}
```

is perfectly fine.

You can use it to read the data from one line or multiple lines.

Comment: Eh? thought scanf is python equivalent for `stdin.readline()`?

Comment: `scanf("%d",&theListOfNumber[x])` might yield better results.

Comment: @Realdeo, that is not correct. `scanf` stops as soon as it finishes reading the data or encounters an error.

Comment: OK, so now it looks like a simple copy-paste from the question.

Comment: Isnt this answer exactly what the question didnt want? _but I'm told not to ask in loop so something like this is not expected._

Comment: I think the confusion for the OP was that he had to enter the data in multiple lines for this to work. I am clarifying that the code will work even when the data is entered in one line.

Comment: The real problem with this code is that the OP has no indication of how many numbers might be entered, and there is no possibility of getting such an indication.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fgets` to read the line, and then use `strtok` to tokenize it, with a space as your delimiter.

See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count = 0;
int getss(int array[], int size)
{
    scanf("%d", &array[count]);
    count++;
    size>1 && getss(array, size - 1);
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int aji[20],n;
    printf("\nRecursion program enter size:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    getss(aji,n);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static void *test;
    static int howManyMember;
    if (argv) {
        printf("How many members are they?");
        scanf("%d", &howManyMember);
        if (howManyMember > 0) {
            int theListOfNumber[howManyMember];
            test = theListOfNumber;
            main(0, 0);
            int x;
            for (x = 0; x < howManyMember; ++x) {
                printf("got: %d\n", theListOfNumber[x]);
            }
        }
    } else if (argc < howManyMember) {
        int *theListOfNumber = test;
        scanf("%d", theListOfNumber + argc);
        main(argc+1, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo.](http://ideone.com/vxjmOH)